# How to execute docker compose run command with ansible?

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

Is there a way to execute "docker compose run" command with ansible? Here is my command that I want to transform into ansible task:

```
docker compose --env-file configs/.env.dev -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml run --rm artisan migrate:refresh
```

I know how to use ansible-shell module for that. Also I've used ansible's docker-compose module to execute ***compose up*** command, but I haven't found any module parameters to specify the specific command for execution.

Comment: I think, the default ansible docker-compose module is not able to "run" a task. It is designed to start/stop the services. So either extend the existing code with a new function is possible or just run the shell command, as it isn't really a "service".

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, I am using shell module. Thanks for the response.